# Concatenate signal names in systemverilog using macro

Tags: macros, verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to concatenate two strings in systemverilog/verilog to create a signal names. 
In my below code snippet, the lhs side seem to work fine, but the rhs side doesn't.
The tool gives an error "bitemp has not been declared yet".

If i pass a hardcorded value say "0" to "clno" parameter, then it works for both lhs and rhs.

```
enter code here
`define strcat_assign_macro(lhs_prestr,lhs_poststr,rhs_prestr,rhs_poststr,clno)  \
 assign lhs_prestr``clno``lhs_poststr = rhs_prestr``clno``rhs_poststr;

module tempmod;
  wire a0temp,b0temp;
  wire a1temp,b1temp;
  wire a2temp,b2temp;

  assign b0temp =1'b1;

  genvar i;
  generate
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    begin
      `strcat_assign_macro(a,temp,b,temp,i)
    end
  endgenerate


  initial begin
   $display (a0temp );
  end

endmodule
```

Comment: after expansion your macro will look like this: `assign aitemp = bitemp;` it will substitute `temp` in place of lhs_poststr and rhs_poststr, i, a, and b will be substituted for other parts. So, you need a different scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Macros get expanded before parsing any Verilog/SystemVerilog syntax. Use an array of wires.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the quick response. Unfortunately the "rhs" is a DUT signal which is not an array. Do you know any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: I think you're stuck if you need to use native syntax.  You could achieve what you're looking for though if you're willing to go the vpp route.  Hard to find links these days (it's old stuff) but there seems to be a (somewhat) maintained version of it at https://github.com/balanx/vbpp

Comment: in your example the module has no  ports. All 'temps' are internal to the module. How does it look in reality? Also, your loop has only 3 iterations. is this it?

Answer (score 0):

Since `defines are expanded before compilation, you are getting those errors.

One way to avoid that is to use a script to automate the define usage and use the same define in the Verilog file.

Here is a sample shell script, which I have made for this purpose. It is a basic script, but I think is sufficient to get you the idea.

```
#!/bin/csh

set b='`'
set a=`egrep -n "^ *${b}strcat_assign_macro" $2 | cut -d: -f1`
set line=`egrep -n "${b}strcat_assign_macro" $2 | cut -d: -f2`

foreach i (`seq $1`)
  set c=`expr $a + $i`
  sed -i "${c}i${line}" temp.ip
  sed -i "${c}s/^\(.*\), *[0-9]* *)/\1, ${i})/g" temp.ip
end
```

Here is the file before & after script.

```
// Before 
karan
shah
   `strcat_assign_macro(b, temp, a, temp, 0)
maheshbhai

// ./temp.sh <Extra Define Lines> <FileName>
./temp.sh 2 input.v

// After
karan
shah
   `strcat_assign_macro(b, temp, a, temp, 0)
`strcat_assign_macro(b, temp, a, temp, 1)
`strcat_assign_macro(b, temp, a, temp, 2)
maheshbhai
```